# save the info of activity android

Tags: android

i have a serious problem in my application, it's about the status of activity, in every activity he has radio buttons check buttons and Edit text, i want the user when he returns to
finds all information that he selected are the same, i read a lot about the cycle of an application in android but i can't make it work, i would be very glad if someone help me.

```
 public class ActivityDeux  extends Activity {



 final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    final String ID = "id";
 DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);



     public void  ajouter(View v) {
         db.open();

         SharedPreferences prefs2 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
         long id = prefs2.getLong(ID, 0);
         db.insertMENAGE2(id,a16,b17,rm_18_1ts,rm_18_2ts,c19,d20,e21);

        db.close();

        } 

  int a16;
  int b17;
  int c19;
  int d20;
  int e21;


private RadioGroup rm_16;
private RadioButton  rm_16_1 ;
private RadioButton  rm_16_2 ;
private RadioButton  rm_16_3 ;
private RadioButton  rm_16_4 ;
private RadioButton  rm_16_5 ;
private RadioButton  rm_16_6 ;
private RadioButton  rm_16_7 ;
EditText  rm_16_autre;
String rm_16_autrets = "";

private RadioGroup   rm_17;
private RadioButton  rm_17_1 ;
private RadioButton  rm_17_2 ;
private RadioButton  rm_17_3;
private RadioButton  rm_17_4 ;
private RadioButton  rm_17_5 ;
EditText  rm_17_autre;
String rm_17_autrets = "";

EditText  rm_18_1 ;
EditText  rm_18_2 ;
String rm_18_1ts  = "";
String rm_18_2ts  = "";

private RadioGroup   rm_19;
private RadioButton  rm_19_1 ;
private RadioButton  rm_19_2 ;
private RadioButton  rm_19_3;
private RadioButton  rm_19_4 ;
private RadioButton  rm_19_5 ;
EditText  rm_19_5_autre;
String rm_19_5_autrets = "";



private RadioGroup   rm_20;
private RadioButton  rm_20_1 ;
private RadioButton  rm_20_2 ;
private RadioButton  rm_20_3;
private RadioButton  rm_20_4 ;
private RadioButton  rm_20_5 ;
EditText  rm_20_5_autre ;
String  rm_20_5_autrets = "";

private RadioGroup   rm_21;
private RadioButton  rm_21_1 ;
private RadioButton  rm_21_2 ;
private RadioButton  rm_21_3;
private RadioButton  rm_21_4 ;
private RadioButton  rm_21_5 ;
EditText  rm_21_5_autre ;
String rm_21_5_autrets =  "";



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_deux);



      rm_16_autre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rm_16_autre);
      rm_17_autre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rm_17_autre);
      rm_18_1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rm_18_1);
      rm_18_2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rm_18_2);
      rm_19_5_autre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rm_19_5_autre);
      rm_20_5_autre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rm_20_5_autre);
      rm_21_5_autre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rm_21_5_autre);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon your requirement, suppose if you want to persisit user selection even when user closes app, and display next time when he returns then the fastest possible way will be

--  `SharedPreferences`, Write all the values user enters in radio boxes and edit boxes into shared preferences using a preferred key(I would suggest widget ids), and in on create initialize them by reading preference again using same keys. you have your solution this way.

Else, if you just want to preserve value for current session, the you can use either of following

-- Use global data holders to preserve values e.g Maps

-- Use `onSaveInstanceState` & `onRestoreInstanceState` callbacks from lifecycle, sample code below

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    outState.putBoolean("WIDGET ID as KEY", value); // Save you values from radio boxes here, whether they are checked or not
    outState.putString("WIDGET ID as KEY", value); // Write values from Editboxes here

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState); 

    // Read the values from bundle, through keys you used to store, and set them to corresponding widgets
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, there is no other way, i have many values and it will take a long time, i am looking for a direct solution, thanks again for responding

Comment: see if user closes the app and comes back to find values he selected as it is, then shared preferences is only available fast solutions, else in a single launch scenario you can go for onSaveInstanceState method, here you can put in all the values you want to preserve and restore it when your activity resumes back,

Comment: could you edit an example code about onSaveInstanceState method, thanks my friend :)

Comment: for example what should i write in value ??

Comment: for radio button write there checkedstate(true/false) for edit text write there values by calling getText

Comment: So this is the only way, there is no faster solution !

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `onSaveBundleInstance(Bundle outBundle)` event, to save the state of your activity. And in `onCreate` of your activity, you'll get the same bundle..

Comment: that's what i am looking for, thanks a lot, could you please edit the code, i will try it and tell you results.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Activity Lifecycle]

Look at the image above. The method onCreate is just called once and the onResume method is called when user returns to the activity (through the back button, for example). For this, you could have a variable that stores the box checked and stored when the user selects it. Then, in onResume method, you can "populate" the boxes.

Comment: well, thanks for idea, but there is no other solution, i mean without trying to use new variables that will save the user info ???